# Reports with multiple orientations and continuation templates

Tags: jasper-reports

I am currently working on a project that has chosen *JasperReports* as their tool to create PDF documents. It is a PHP project, using web services to talk to *JasperReports* to create the PDF's from pre-designed templates.

Unfortunately, everyone on the project has very little experience with *JasperReports* and *Jaspersoft Studio*.

One of our requirements is to build a report, where the first page is landscape and has many text fields on them, 2 of which (if the text overflows) need to continue onto 2 different reports (both portrait).

We are having trouble finding a solution to allow multiple orientations, and continuing the 2 different text areas on 2 different continuation sheets.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can "join" two reports, for example. See the [JasperReports - Batch Export Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html#batchexport) article.